# Why is Matt Horner embarrassed of Mira Han?

Tags: starcraft-2

Their encounter and marriage thereafter *is* a bit awkward, but still.

Is there any valid reason for Matt to be embarrassed while Jim Raynor is talking to Han?

Light spoiler: He waves his hands in the background, frantically trying to tell Jim "pretend I'm not here" without letting Han hear :)

Comment: I assume you've never been divorced?

Comment: Actually, I _have_ been divorced. Still no grounds for an embarrassment. What's your point?

Comment: [joking tone] then perhaps YOU are Mira Han!
In any case, you probably didn't get married by accident like Matt Horner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any definitive information on this. However there are a number of possibilities we can infer.

He may be embarrassed about:

- Her superficial attributes (e.g. her pink hair, glowing cybernetic eye)
- The circumstances surrounding their [marriage](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Mira_Han#Matrimony). Winning a wife through a poker game could be considered embarrassing.
- According to a description of his [personality](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Matt_Horner#Personality_and_Abilities): "Horner has strong moral principles. He has a desire to make the universe a better place..." Thus Horner may have an aversion to Han's work as a mercenary.

Remember however that we don't really have enough information about Matt Horner, or Mira Han, to really say why Matt Horner is embarrassed of Mira Han. It may simply be because:

1. Mira Han has undocumented and uncontrollable flatulence.
2. Matt Horner never took the time to get to know the real Mira Han.
3. Matt Horner prefers the company of men.

Comment: +1 Winning a wife in the poker game must be the convincing argument.